# IS there a way to increase the height of the text field apart from increasing the font size

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am trying to increase the height of the UITextField in my app through IB. I have defined these textfield in my IB so i think it needs to be done through IB. Please let me know if there is a way to do it either through IB or through code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As UITextField subclasses UIView, it inherits UIView's `initWithFrame`method.

```
NSInteger myCustomHeight = 237;
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, myCustomHeight)];
```

If u want do do it through IB then replace the last line with:

```
textField.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, myCustomHeight);
```

This assumes textField is an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @SamanB: Is there a way to align the content vertically....as my content is going upside and i want it to be in center.

Comment: Try: textField.alignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; Also try to look at the documentation for UITextField it is where I just looked to answere you. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Comment: this is only for the horizontal alignment and not for the vertical alignment.

Comment: You cant change the virtical alignment, u could try rotating the textfield by using its transform property.

Comment: This definitely works. Just want to add that if you added the text fields through interface builder you should put the code in the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the height of UITextField is possible.  But you cannot get text on next line, you can write text on only one line.  It you want to have Textfield look alike you can use UITextView with editing option where you can increase the height and can have text on multiple lines.

Comment: You can change the height, check the example above.

Comment: There is way look the post below.

Comment: It will just increase the height.  But Do you want to write text on next line?

Comment: its just the login fields.... also do you know if there is a way to align the content horizontally because in my case the content is going upside.

Comment: Try using  textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft or Right or Center.